# Formatting multiple line statement in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

In vim a long statements like

```
 if ( (image == null) || (image.getFileHash() == null) || (image.getFileImage() == null) )
```

gets indented like this when I hit an enter before the second OR

```
if ( (image == null) || (image.getFileHash() == null)
        || (image.getFileImage() == null) ) {
```

is there a way to set vim to indent it like

```
if ( (image == null) || (image.getFileHash() == null)
    || (image.getFileImage() == null) ) {
```

i.e., aligning it with the column after ( of the first previous line.

With dash-tom-bang's help was able to solve a part of the
problem. However, now the curly brackets are not aligned as expected
if `{` starts on the same line.

```
if ( (image == null) || (image.getFileHash() == null) ||
     (image.getFileImage() == null) )
{

}

if ( (image == null) || (image.getFileHash() == null) ||
     (image.getFileImage() == null) ) {

     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting that controls this is `cinoptions`, see `:help cinoptions-values`.

Add this to your .vimrc to align with the most local unclosed parenthesis.  (You can give extra indent in spaces by giving a different number, including negatives.  You can indent N tabstops by using Ns.)

```
set cinoptions=(0
```

The default value is 2s, which would indent two tabs past the open paren; hopefully this is what you're seeing.  :)

Comment: Hit another snag

    if ( (image == null) || (image.getFileHash() == null) ||
         (image.getFileImage() == null) ) {

         }

The closing curly bracket aligns to '(' rather than the if statement.

Comment: Look at the help document I reference above, it'll give you all sorts of configuration options.  The closing brace should default to the "correct" spot, but you could try adding `}0` to your `cinoptions` to see if that changes the behavior.  Another possibility is that if your parentheses aren't matched, the autoformatter does all sorts of things that you might not find desirable...

Comment: Tried `}0` and couldn't find a way to do it. I updated the original post to show exactly what I am seeing.

Comment: Odd. That case works fine for me with Vim 7.3 on Windows.  Maybe check your indent settings, does `set cindent?` reveal that cindent is on?  I have autoindent, nosmartindent, cindent.

Comment: I tried with autoindent, nosmartindent, cindent. same problem. I am, however, using MacVim ( VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jan 16 2012 19:11:00) MacOS X (unix) version )